# Custom string sort gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault

I am solving a problem in which you are given a bunch of numbers in string format and you have to concatenate them in such a way that the result is the maximum number possible.
E.g:

Input: 6 61 68

Output: 68661

So I am using a custom sorter with `std::sort` to sort the strings and I am getting weird, random segmentation faults when accessing string using `.at()`

I am using this command to run the code

```
g++ -Wextra -Wall -pipe -O2 -std=c++14 largest_number_problem.cpp -lm && ./a.out
```

output of `g++ --version`

```
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

The output is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Note: There is no string whose length is zero in the array. Take a look at the code.

Sometimes I get: can't access memory at location 0x0.

My Code:

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

bool sortNos(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    int n1 = s1.size(), n2 = s2.size();
    bool result = 0;
    
    while (i1 < n1 && i2 < n2)
    {
        if (s1.at(i1) != s2.at(i2))
        {
            result = s1.at(i1) > s2.at(i2);
            return result;
        }
        i1++;
        i2++;
    }
    if (i1 == n1 && i2 == n2)
    {
        // strings are equal
        return 1;
    }
    if (i1 == n1)
    {
        result = s1.at(0) > s2.at(i2);
    }
    else if (i2 == n2)
    {
        result = s2.at(0) < s1.at(i1);
    }
    return result;
}
string largest_number(vector<string> &a)
{
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), &sortNos);
    std::stringstream ret;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        ret << a[i];
    }
    string result;
    ret >> result;
    return result;
}
void test()
{
    vector<string> a;
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("4");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("6");
    a.push_back("3");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("8");
    a.push_back("10");
    a.push_back("7");
    a.push_back("2");
    a.push_back("5");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("1");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("9");
    a.push_back("5");
    largest_number(a);
}
int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `std::sort` wants a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). In particular, two elements can't be both be ordered before the other.

Comment: The best way to ensure that your program works with arbitrary inputs is to use small and systematic test cases, not huge random ones.

Comment: use `vector<string> a = { "2", "8", ...};` to cut your number of lines by half

Comment: read 
[Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The first line makes your code non-standard non-portable for no good reason. You prevent others to compile your code, thats the main effect. Why do you do that?

Comment: @idclev463035818 thank you for your suggestions. Since this is in the realm of competitive programming, it is preferred to do it that way in order to save time.

Comment: you are not saving any time by this two lines, though in the realm of competitive programming such myths are rather common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see the main problem is this piece of code:

```
if (i1 == n1 && i2 == n2)
{
    // strings are equal
    return 1;
}
```

which should be

```
if (i1 == n1 && i2 == n2)
{
    // strings are equal
    return false;
}
```

The first version implies that two identical strings should be sorted *before each other*, i.e. you couldn't decide which comes first. You violated the requirements for the comparator and experience undefined behaviour. One specific requirement is that for *any* `a` and `b` when `sortNos(a, b) == true` then `sortNos(b, a)` must be `false`. But this doesn't hold if `a == b`.

It should worik when you return 0 (or better `false`) instead of 1.

Comment: as @molbdnilo pointed out, I tried to fix the code the same way as you've mentioned.